# Question about anchors in blazor phone app <a href="tel: xxx"> xxx </x>"

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I'm making an phone APP with blazor and it seems that I can't make the anchor work to open the phone app with a click on a phone number like that.

Anything will do for me, an @onclick, an , or whatever works. I'm far from an expert in c# so talk to me like I'm five.

I tried alot of things, that I can't list before asking a question about this here =)

```
<a href="tel:@NavMenu.contact.Mobile">@NavMenu.contact.Mobile</a>
```

Comment: I take it `@NavMenu.contact.Mobile` is a valid and proper formatted phone number?
This isn't much related to C#, this is a feature browsers individually decide to support, including whichever browser your phone is using.

Comment: @RobinGM Thanks for the fast anwser. It's not a browser, it's an app. A blazor hybrid app. (yhea I didnt choose what I work on/with)

Comment: Blazor Hybrid and Blazor Server Side are not the same, I suggest mentioning this.
Thing is Blazor Hybrid is sort of like Xamarin but without the features. It's not as mature either. Blazor Hybrid compiles your app instead of running in the browser so odds are the anchors like tel: and magnet: have not been implemented yet.

Comment: Hi again @RobinGM. Thanks again for anwering so fast. 

I know its not quite the same, but I coulnd add a blazor-hybrid tag beaucause it doens't exist. 

And thanks for the feedback about anchors for tel: (mailto: also doesnt work btw)